# 403 Forbidden error trying to access to appengine.google.com from a specific IP

Tags: google-app-engine, digital-ocean

I don't know why, but today I can't connect to any GAE domain from one on my VPS located in Amsterdam (Digital Ocean as provider). I'm getting a 403 forbidden error with the message: "Your client does not have permission to get URL from this server.  (Client IP address: )".

However, the rest of the VPS in the same location can connect without problems and even the problematic VPS was connecting perfectly yesterday.

What's happening here??

If I hit against my GAE app I don't see the request/response in the log file.... so it seems that my app does not launch that 403. Moreover, the same is happening if I send my request against http://appengine.google.com, I get a 403 forbidden error so definitively my GAE app is not the problem.

Is google blocking the VPS ip??? why??? due to a location policy??? I don't think so because I have a set of VPS in the same location and they are working fine. Maybe a abuse report regarding this ip??? How can I figure it out???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the IP has been used for DDoS or some other attack in the past and is blacklisted in the outermost firewall of App Engine. Try getting a new IP address for that host and it should work as expected.

Comment: Yeah! I know that I could fix it quickly just getting a new IP, but the main reason of my question is to know what's the cause of this issue in order to avoid that it happens again. Yesterday it was working fine, today it does not, my VPS is apparently secure so I don't expect a DoS attack in the last 24 hours from it.... so... maybe google has a delay when it detects a suspect IP and it block it? no idea, any plan to get more info is welcome.

Comment: @Curro that is a bit unpredictable. I've had the same happen on several occasions when interacting with my app engine app from AWS and Rackspace. There's really not much you can do about how Google blacklists IPs and in fact they don't even have a way to request white listing that I know of.

Comment: Well... then it seems to be a common problem in any cloud provider (AWS, Rackspace, Digital Ocean...). So nothing much to do. Thanks rdodev!